# The system cannot find the file specified with ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

In the process of using the ffmpeg module to edit video files i used the subprocess module

The code is as follows:

```
#trim bit

import subprocess
import os
seconds = "4"
mypath=os.path.abspath('trial.mp4')
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i',mypath, '-ss', seconds, 'trimmed.mp4'])
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\moviepy-master\resizer.py", line 29, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i',mypath, '-ss', seconds, 'trimmed.mp4'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 168, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

After looking up similar problems i understood that the module is unable to pick the video file because it needs its path, so i took the absolute path. But in spite of that the error still shows up.
The module where this code was saved and the video file trial.mp4 are in the same folder.

Comment: And from which path did you call your script? This should matter. Manually check ```mypath```! (and maybe use os.path.exists() for more checking). **Edit**: error is ambiguous and i'm not even sure if the problem is within ffmpeg. Is ffmpeg in your system-path? Can it be called from console (like you do here, no absolute path!)?

Comment: I'm quite sure that the problem is that it's not finding `ffmpeg` - if the error was that it couldn't find the input file, it would not come in a neat Python exception, but as an error message on standard error from ffmpeg.

Comment: try installing ffmpeg with chocolatey: `choco install ffmpeg`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `WindowsError` you see does not refer to the video file but to the `ffmpeg` executable itself. The call to `subprocess.call` has no idea that `trimmed.mp4` is a filename you are passing. Windows knows that the first parameter ought to be an executable file and reports back to the interpreter that it can't find it.

Double-check that `ffmpeg` can be executed in the environment your interpreter is running in. You may either add it to your `PATH` or specify the full path to `ffmpeg.exe`.

Comment: If you talking about setting the environment variable to ffmpeg.exe , then it was already set before i ran this code .

Comment: Is it actually correct and picked up by the interpreter? Opening a shell and typing `ffmpeg` should work then. In any case, the error says it's not there.

Comment: Thanks, for me, despite being in my environment variables, i had to add the full path to ffmpeg.exe! The ffmpeg command was callable from cmd without issue but not via the python subprocess or os.system

Answer (score 13):

None of the above answers worked for me.

I got it working, by opening Anaconda Navigator > CMD prompt.

```
conda install ffmpeg
```

Comment: life saver, problem was not the video file after all... what a misleading error message

Answer (score 8):

This answer is directed at Windows users of the `ffmpeg-python` library since this question is the first search result for a stricter instance of the same issue.

Adding on to user2722968's answer because neither of the existing answers solved the problem for me.

As of this post, `ffmpeg-python` uses `subprocess.Popen` to run `ffmpeg`. Per [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue17023) issue, `subprocess` does not look in `Path` when resolving names, so even if FFmpeg is installed and in your `Path` *and* you can run it from CMD/PowerShell, `ffmpeg-python` may not be able to use it.

My solution was to copy `ffmpeg.exe` into the Python environment where `python.exe` is. This workaround seems far from ideal but it seems to have solved the problem for me.

Comment: I recently found that when my PyQt5 app converted to an exe, it still needs ffmpeg.exe in the same folder my app.exe is located.

Answer (score 7):

Most of the answers didn't work. Here is what worked for me using conda env:

```
pip uninstall ffmpeg-python
conda install ffmpeg
pip install ffmpeg-python
```

Just the conda installation gives library not found error. Didn't try uninstalling conda library either but this works.

Comment: interesting... this does not work: pip install ffmpeg ...but this works: conda install ffmpeg

Comment: @perpetualstudent that's because the module is called`ffmpeg-python` in PyPI, so you need to run `pip install ffmpeg-python`.

Comment: As a user of Anaconda, this worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue!
And I FOUND A SOLUTION.

I realised, viewing all these answers that I need to install ffmpeg. I tried 'pip install ffmpeg' but that didn't work. What worked was copying the ffmpeg.exe file to the folder that python.exe is in.
Thats what someone up here mentioned. Thank you!
To download the ffmpeg.exe file, download the zip file from https://github.com/GyanD/codexffmpeg/releases/tag/2022-06-06-git-73302aa193

Answer (score 1):

First Uninstall all pip libraries

```
pip uninstall ffmpeg
pip uninstall ffmpeg-python
```

Then install using conda

```
conda install ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use 'ffmpeg.exe' or its linux binary, you need this

```
conda install ffmpeg
```

Then you will call it via subprocess or os.system() in your code.
And make sure you will run a different thread to run ffmpeg code otherwise there will be a huge bottleneck in your main thread.

```
class SaveAll():
    def init(self):
        super(SaveAll, self).__init__()

    def save(self):
        try:
            command = "ffmpeg -i {} -c copy -preset ultrafast {}"format(...)
            os.system(command)
        except ffmpeg.Error as e:
            print (e.stout, file=sys.stderr)
            print (e.stderr, file=sys.stderr)

    def run(self):
        self.thread= threading.Thread(target=self.save)
        self.thread.start()
        self.thread.join(1)

...

saver = SaveAll()
saver.start()
```